# how to set background image to textview in android?

Tags: android

i want to set background image to textview with its height and width.means if the textview size small than it set it small image if its size big than it draw large image to that text view.

Comment: Isn't that is how Android background image works by default?

Comment: Could you make the question a bit more clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try a 9-patch image. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) for details.

Comment: oh dear i olready try this.i think u dnt understand my question.here i tell u my problem.actully m making chat application and i want to set bubble background images to chat messages.only simple chating work.i get the editext value in string. and pass that string value result to handler.how can i set bubble to that string result according to its size

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, a 9-patch is the way to go. What exactly have you tried and didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

maybe a xml drawable is helpful, depends to waht kind of image you want to load, store the following xml in your drawable folder and declare the cml as background for your textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid
        android:color="#ef4444"/>
        <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#992f2f"/>
        <corners
        android:radius="4dp"/>
        <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>  
    <shape> 
        <gradient
        android:startColor="#ef4444"
        android:endColor="#992f2f"
        android:angle="270"/>
        <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#992f2f"/>
        <corners
        android:radius="4dp"/>
        <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: oh dear i olready try this.i think u dnt understand my question.here i tell u my problem.actully m making chat application and i want to set bubble background images to chat messages.only simple chating work.i get the editext value in string. and pass that string value result to handler.how can i set bubble to that string result according to its size.

Comment: then try the 9-patch images and set the textview size to "warp_content"